# Rails has_many through fails on create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have 3 Models:

```
User
has_many :user_projects
has_many :projects,    :through => :user_projects

Project
has_many :user_projects, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :users, :through => :user_projects, :uniq => true


UserProject
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
```

I then have a form that allows the creation of a new Project and can assign Users to it.

The form is:

```
<% form_for(@project, :html => { :id => 'project_create'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name, 'Project Name' %>
<% @users.each do |user| %>    
    <%= user.username %>: <%= check_box_tag("project[user_project_ids][]",user.id) %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

However, for some reason a record must exist in `UserProject` table for it to work.

Any idea on how to create the association if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Could you post your form so we can see what you have?

Answer (score 1):

Your associations are incorrect.

User

```
has_many :user_projects
has_many :projects, :through => :user_projects
```

Project

```
has_many :user_projects, :dependent => :destroy 
has_many :users, :through => user_projects
```

UserProject

```
belongs_to :project 
belongs_to :user
```

Update your associations as above and post your results.

Comment: Hi Shreyas

Not sure why it wasn't in there, blind copy/paste - down to tiredness I guess!

Updated model associations

Same result:

Couldn't find all UserProjects with IDs (1,2)

Its running:

SELECT * FROM `user_projects` WHERE (`user_projects`.`id` IN (1,2)) 

Seems to be using the ID of the user to try and find a user_project row (which doesn't exist)

Comment: Have you tried using formtastic ? Its much easier dealing with forms such as these using it. It automatically detects associations.

Comment: I'm on a machine that doesn't have admin priviledges, and so cannot install Bundler which is what Formtastic requires :/